# How to get id of the message tag in smack?

Tags: android, smack

I tried to get the id inside the message tag

```
<message to='one@localhost/117407446208446435445346' from='sun@localhost/92794770693658404575218' id='z2UD4-17' xml:lang='en'><x xmlns="jabber:x:event"><displayed/><id>uQkZG-17</id></x></message>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to [parse the XML](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml). There are a lot of libraries that can help. Android recommends using [XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser).